# What is the antonym of 'dorso'?

Tags: antónimos

> Bill tomó un folleto de vitaminas y escribió en el **dorso**...

The meaning is pretty obvious: wrote on the back of...

What if Bill fancied to write his message on the *front* side of the leaflet? What word would be chosen?

Comment: FWIW, this word has the same origin as the "dorsal" fin on fish. It's on their "back" from an anatomical perspective.

Comment: @RobertColumbia funny thing is that we also call _dorsal_ to the number that runners wear in races, despite it being normally in the front

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct word is '**anverso**'. See the 2nd definition in the Dictionary of the Real Academia de la Lengua:

> [anverso](https://dle.rae.es/?w=anverso) Del fr. envers 'envés', y este del lat. inversus 'invertido'.
>   1. m. En las monedas y medallas, haz que se considera principal por llevar el busto de una persona o por otro motivo.
>   2. m. Impr. Cara en que va impresa la primera página de un pliego.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple antonyms for "dorso". I have found for instance:

- **anverso**
- **haz**
- **cara**

Comment: The easiest way is to search at "Google" for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=antonimo+dorso  You will see there are a lot of results offeringmultiple antonyms for "dorso".